# Java toString() Hiding information

Tags: java

How do I get my toString method to return only certain parts of a String, for example I have a variable for a name and surname with a constructor. I want to use a toString method so that it returns only the first letter of each name filling the rest with a placeholder for example a '-'

```
enter code here

private String foreame = null;
private String surname = null;

public FullName(String forename, String surname) 
{
   this.forename = forename;
   this.surname = surname;
}
```

So that I could get an output like 'J---- R--' for the name James Roy

Comment: Override the  `toString()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the class, Override the toString method as such:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return forename.replaceAll("\\B\\w", "-")) + " " + surname.replaceAll("\\B\\w", "-"));   
}
```

or, more concisely:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return (forename + " " + surname).replaceAll("\\B\\w", "-");
}
```

The replaceAll will replace all but the first character in the Strings with the token "-", achieving your desired outcome.

[Here's a very helpful link for working with Regex.](https://lexikos.github.io/v1/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm) Note that because java uses the '\' as an escape token, you need to use two as shown.

Comment: I missed that requirement.

Comment: Ah yeah this works great thanks,
Could you explain a bit about how the "\\B\\w" works for if I wanted to do for example just the last letter or both first and last, what are the symbols actually doing

Comment: The "\\B\\w" is a regular expression. The \B checks to ensure that the current character is NOT at a word boundary, hence excluding the first character. The \w matches any word character (Short for [a-zA-Z_0-9]). As a combination, it will exclude the first character (as it is on the word boundary), and match the remaining. If you wanted for both first and last you would use "\\B\\w\\B", for the same reason. I'll add some helpful Regex links.